# scipy curve_fit doesn't vary some parameters depending on initial values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm just fitting a linear function to some data, but ran into issues with the default initial values being set to 1 in curve_fit. I'm therefore looking to change the initial values, but the code has to be pretty general as I'm looking to apply it to different y variables. So I set the intercept value to just be the average of the 1st 20 datapoints, as this should be pretty close to the optimal answer (my x values are offset to start near 0). But I made the slope 0, as for different variables there could be any sign relationship, or none.

However, with the slope at zero in my example, curve_fit doesn't vary this slope - and instead changes the intercept to best fit the data, pulling it away from where it should really be. This behavious doesn't change when the value is changed to be non-zero but still tiny - in the example 0.01 and 0.001 have the same effect. It gives a 'Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated' warning when it doesn't vary the parameter.

There data are all float64, so it's not related directly to this previously discussed issue [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9581).

I'm not sure if this is the best way to share but I've uploaded the data on DropBox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/216bad3swo7k6hswoluae/example_data.pkl?rlkey=786nbf2zadjgvo9h1qfywixgq&dl=0). The code below along with this data should reproduce the issue. My scipy is version 1.11.3.

Grateful for any ideas on why this might be happening!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

def fit1(x, alpha, beta_t):
    yhat = alpha + beta_t*x
    return yhat


with open('example_data.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    xs, ys = pickle.load(handle)
    
plt.plot(xs, ys, color='blue')

for guess in [0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]:
        
    init_guess = np.zeros(2)
    init_guess[0] = np.mean(ys[:20])
    init_guess[1] = guess
    params, _ = curve_fit(fit1, xs, ys, p0=init_guess)
    
    plt.plot(xs, fit1(xs, *params), label=f'init_guess[1] = {init_guess[1]}')


plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Is your data unsorted? It is best to have your data sorted by the x-values. Your data is also very large, so it might be worth scaling it as well.

Comment: if you're fitting a linear function, you shouldn't be using curve_fit in the first place, use [np.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy-linalg-lstsq) instead

Comment: @jared Thanks - scaling prevented the issue, and sorting the data looks nicer so will do that too.

Comment: @Nin17 thanks - sorry I should have noted, I'm writing this for general user-inputted functions so am keeping it general to allow for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the ideas mentioned in the comments:

If you scale the data so that most points are around 1, that gets rid of both the error about being unable to estimate covariance, and allows it to fit the linear regression no matter what the initial guess is.

```
    params, _ = curve_fit(fit1, xs, ys/1e9, p0=init_guess)
    plt.plot(xs, fit1(xs, *params) * 1e9, label=f'init_guess[1] = {init_guess[1]}')
```

[image: scaling result]

You could also use [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) rather than multiplying and dividing by a constant.

Alternately, if you use [scipy.stats.linregress()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), it can find the solution directly, without an initial guess or scaling:

```
res = scipy.stats.linregress(xs, ys)
plt.plot(xs, ys, color='blue')
plt.plot(xs, res.intercept + res.slope*xs)
```

[image: linregress result]

<sub>(Note: this is after I sorted both xs and ys by xs.)</sub>

linregress() is also about 20x faster than curve_fit() for this dataset, because curve_fit() is more flexible.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm not sure why rescaling prevents it, (and I think it would be best if this was flagged up in the warning message...) but it's working now so much appreciated!

Comment: @chrisdwells In general, gradient based optimization will have a lot of trouble with functions that have either really big gradients, or really small gradients. Rescaling is a way of avoiding that.